# Is the word "also" related to the phrase "although it may be so"?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

Note that the word `"also"` is a sub-sequence of the phrase `"although that may be so"`?

```
ALTHOUGH THAT MAY BE SO
AL                   SO
```

| A | L | T | H | O | U | G | H | `chr(32)` | I | T | `chr(32)` | M | A | Y | `chr(32)` | B | E | `chr(32)` | S | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | **L** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | **∅** | S | O |

Comment: I'm about 98% sure this is coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't. Here's a reference:
[Etymonline *also*][1]

"Old English eallswa "just as, even as, as if, so as, likewise," contraction of eal swa, from all "altogether" + so. **Originally an emphatic form of so**."

(emphasis added)

Also, note that *although* is concessive, that is, it concedes something before introducing something that seems counter to it. *Also* doesn't have that twist.